# Combine nestjs microservices into one app

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices

I have multiple microservices in my nest js like user, campaign etc. and one server app which communicate with those microservices. How can I ccombine those microservices and server app into 1 module (or whatever it is called).

The user microservice app.module.ts file:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `${process.cwd()}/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    AppConfigModule,
    DatabaseProviderModule,
    UsersModule,
    RedisModule,
    JwtModule.register({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY as string }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The web-server's app.module.ts file:

```
@Module({
  imports: [UserModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```